# Java8 streams Multiple for loop handling with if clause

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream

I am new to Java 8 and I want to handle multiple for loop with if clause in java 8 to update list of one objects based on the other.

Below is the code using java `for each` loop. How this can be converted to java 8 streams based?

```java
for (MonthlyData monthly : MonthlyDataList) {
    for (MonthlyTsData mts : MonthlyTsDataList {
        if (monthly.getMasterId() == mts.getMasterId() 
            && monthly.getMasterSector() == mts.getMasterSector()
        ) {
            mts.setFsName(monthly.getFsName());
            mts.setQsName(monthly.getQsName());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not everything that can be done with streams should be done with streams.

Comment: This question needs more details, what each object represents in order to provide an accurate answer. However you can try this 



```MonthlyTsDataList.stream.filter(mts - > (monthly.getMasterId() == mts.getMasterId()) && (monthly.getMasterSector() == mts.getMasterSector())).map(mts - > {
            mts.setFsName(monthly.getFsName());
            mts.setQsName(monthly.getQsName());
            return mts;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());```

Answer (score 3):

Stream API may be used for this task and the following solution is possible but it would be just a more verbose mimic of the loop-based version:

```java
MonthlyDataList.stream()
    .forEach(monthly -> {
        MonthlyTsDataList.stream()
            .filter(mts -> monthly.getMasterId() == mts.getMasterId()
                && monthly.getMasterSector() == mts.getMasterSector()
            )
            .findFirst()  // Optional<MonthlyTsData>
            .ifPresent(mts -> {
                    mts.setFsName(monthly.getFsName());
                    mts.setQsName(monthly.getQsName());
            });
    });
```